# Queries on the Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to ask the below queries. Apologies if it was asked before, I couldn't find them.

1. W.r.t the new pricing it is mentioned as "You can send us your analytics events any time without being limited by your app's request limit." - Is it that any interactions made for the Parse analytics does not count towards to the overall api request limit set for the app?
2. From the answers to the queries posted a while back in the forums, there was some distinction between the normal and premium customers - Is there any now..?
3. I am using the android sdk - Just out of curiosity, can two objects(or more) have the same object id by any chance?

Thanks.

Comment: These should be split up into different posts. Two of them are not about programming so they don't belong on [so] at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to all of your questions:

1. Correct.  Analytics does not contribute to API request limits or burst limit.
2. On the new pricing, there is no longer a distinction.  All previously "Pro-Only" features are available to everyone.
3. No, multiple objects cannot / will not have duplicate objectId values.